Choosing the correct evaluation metric between F1-score and Area under the Precision-Recall Curve (AUPRC)
We're currently working on detecting specific objects (e.g. poultry farms, hospitals)  from satellite images. We've modeled the problem as a binary image classification task (i.e. classifying images as farm/not farm) and are using gradient-weighted class activation maps (CAMs) to further localize the objects within the image. We do this to avoid the high cost of manually annotating bounding boxes around the objects since acquiring binary labels is much cheaper. So far, the CAMs work great for localizing the objects without needing bounding box annotations.
For the image classification task, we started by optimizing the F1-score, with the probability threshold set to a default value of 0.5. But we later realized that because the optimal threshold will depend on the end user's tolerance for false positives and false negatives, it might actually be better to optimize the area under the precision-recall curve (AUPRC). As we're integrating human-in-the-loop validation, we're currently developing a user interface where the users can dynamically change the threshold depending on how many predictions they have the resources to validate on the ground.
Right now, the range for the adjustable threshold is from 0.5 to 1.0 because we're only generating CAMs for the positive predictions, i.e. predictions with probabilities > 0.5 for the positive class. It doesn't seem to make sense to generate CAMs for all predictions (even those with lower confidence scores for the positive class) as it's computationally intensive and less likely to produce meaningful outputs, as these low-probability images will likely not contain the object.
With this, would it still make sense to optimize the AUPRC or should we stick with optimizing the F1-score? Should we generate our own custom performance metric based on our unique use case? Thanks!
Edit: Given that we only generate CAMs for predictions with probabilities > 0.5, would it make sense to calculate the AUPRC by considering only probabilities > 0.5?
This has been cross-posted on Stack Overflow.

Your edit asks a different question that should be posted separately. $//$ You issued the bounty after I had posted my answer. Is there something lacking in my answer?

You write yourself that you face a dependence on the "end user's tolerance for false positives and false negatives" so metrics which use a threshold, e.g. F1 should be out of the discussion immediately.

I can't imagine why you want to move this matter of statistics to the programming venue (the answer to this question involves zero programming), but please do not vandalize your question.

It's the same question, just that it is within the scope of one community and outside the scope of the other. Stack Overflow should have closed or migrated the question. But how they moderate their Stack is their business. What I do care about is the statistics content of your question, and I find it problematic that not one answer at Stack Overflow addresses strictly proper scoring rules or makes explicit the difference between the raw predictions and derived classifications.

I don't care about the fifteen points for an accepted answer, but I do want you to understand the statistics content that those answers are missing.

Rolled back the edits, which, dissociated from the rest of the discussion, basically vandalized the original question

@meraxes This is the proper venue.

These do not evaluate the same model, so you have to decide what model you want to deploy.
The area under the precision-recall curve evaluates the raw model predictions (converted to ranks).
The $F_1$ score evaluates a two-stage pipeline of making the raw model predictions followed by a decision-rule about how to convert those raw model predictions to classifications.
There are legitimate arguments for both the one-stage and two-stage pipelines.
In the one-stage pipeline that you would evaluate with area under the precision-recall curve, you allow the operator additional flexibility to control false positives and false negatives.
However, that additional flexibility puts more on the user, who has presumably paid good money for you to deliver a product that makes life easier for them. Imagine my carpenter just dropping off boards and a nail gun. "No, I wanted you to build my house," I would think. It might be reasonable for you to assess what level of tradeoff is reasonable and fix a decision-rule (a threshold) that will work well and let your user operate on autopilot, with you having done all of the hard work.
Depending on what your user wants and what you want to deliver, either can be defended.
A third option worth knowing about is to evaluate your predictions on strictly proper scoring-rules like Brier score and log loss (Efron's and McFadden's pseudo $R^2$ standardize those scores). An advantage here is that, unlike area under the curve and $F_1$ score, these will evaluate model calibration: if your predicted probability values align with the reality of how often events happen. An advantage of having good calibration is that the predictions have a literal interpretation as event probability, while you could have a perfect area under the PR curve of $1$ yet have awful calibration (ditto for area under the ROC curve).
Finally, working with raw model outputs allows you to have an "I don't know" zone. There can be two categories but three (maybe more) actions to take.
I would argue that, if you do not know the costs of wrong decisions, you have no business making decisions, and you need to evaluate the raw predictions using strictly proper scoring rules. If your customer does not accept this and demands hard classifications, then you have additional information to gather to make a system that delivers decisions aligned with the consequences of those decisions.
I will not tell you what you should evaluate, as that requires you to determine what you value, though I hope this post gives you a sense of how to consider what you value and how to assess your work once you know what you value.

Great answer! I love the carpenter picture :) and the discussion about calibration, proper scoring rules and the decision areas and actions to take! Very well put together
